# Windows 10: AAC Support

Tags: windows, windows-update, bluetooth, aac

I bought new AirPods Max for various reasons. They work flawlessly when connecting them via Bluetooth to my Windows PC when only listening to music. The microphone quality is, however, atrocious.

After spending several hours on Google, I learned that Windows does not support AAC, which is the reason for the bad microphone quality. Best explanation can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/airpods/comments/kg3w4n/airpods_max_terrible_mic_quality_on_windows_10/).

Afterwards I learned that AAC support for Windows 10 is planned as per various news sites for 21H2 ([link here](https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/04/29/microsoft-to-add-aac-bluetooth-audio-support-in-windows-10-update)).

So I tried joining the Windows Insider Program and updating to 21H2 just to get the AAC support and finally be able to use my AirPods Max properly. As per [this link](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/08/18/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-19044-1198-21h2/), 21H2 has been released to the Release Preview Channel. Since my PC is not suited for Windows 11 (1st generation Ryzen CPU, just 3 years old), I was defaulted to the Release Preview Channel.

Problem 1: No matter what I do (restarts, manual Windows Update starts, ...) Windows Update does not offer me the upgrade to 21H2. How do I get it ahead of schedule?

Problem 2: As per [this link](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/08/18/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-19044-1198-21h2/), the listed changes suddenly don't contain the AAC support listed on many news articles from April / May. So... Does 21H2 have AAC support or not? Where do I find information about that? Trying to find information on this via Google or Microsoft sites is just horrible and I wasted enough hours.

Out of pure curiosity: How is it, that other Bluetooth headsets sound pretty good, just the AirPods Max do not? What codec are they using, if Windows is not supporting AAC currently?

Disclaimer: Upgrading to Windows 11 Beta is out of question (I have found reports online that Windows 11 seems to have AAC support), as my Ryzen CPU does not official support it.